# How to use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger as class variable in Azure FunctionApp?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

***Question :***

How to declare a ILogger as class variable and use them for logging ?

***NOTES : ***

1. I need to develop Azure Function App where TraceWritter is used as default.
   While writting UnitTest, TraceWritter is difficult. Instead iam using ILogger.
2. In funtion app , iam passing the log variable to all methods from Initial RUN Method. ( This is not the right way to do this. )
3. I need to declare ILogger as a class Variable and use them in all places.

so , How to do this.

***Sample Code***

```
public class addClass
    {
      //  private static ILogger LOGGER = ---???-----  // I need to declare here.

        private void add(ILogger log)       // Iam using like this. This is not rite way of programming to pass to all methods.
        {
          int a = 10;
          int b=4;

                log.LogInformation((a+b));

        }

        private void addM()     // Using the class variable.    
        {
          int a = 10;
          int b = 4;

                log.LogInformation((a+b));

        }
    }
```

Help me out of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please try initialize the ILogger in the constructor of addClass? like below:  `ILogger logger; public AddClass(ILogger logger){this.logger = logger;}`

Comment: `ILogger` is an interface, you need an instance of a class that implements `ILogger`. Presumably that class is called `Logger`, so your commented line would be something like `private static ILogger LOGGER = new Logger(/*parameters*/);` You can then call `LOGGER.LogInformation("log message");` in any method within the class. Note although your comment says "Using the class variable", `log` is not a class variable it is a local variable within `add()` and not accessible in `addM`.

Comment: Ya , I have done this way . But how to unit test this function ? When I write unit-test case  , it says "LOG contains null value " . @IvanYang

Comment: private static ILogger LOGGER = new Logger(/*parameters*/); I cant get this. @iakobski

Comment: can you share some simple demo code? in function and unit test?